# What is utility function and how to use it in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I want to use a library called react-native-sketch-canvas in my app. Library has some functions which they called util functions in github.

```
export default class RNSketchCanvas extends React.Component<RNSketchCanvasProps & ViewProperties> {
  clear(): void
  undo(): number
  addPath(data: Path): void
  deletePath(id: number): void
  save(): void
  nextStrokeWidth(): void

  static MAIN_BUNDLE: string
  static DOCUMENT: string
  static LIBRARY: string
  static CACHES: string
```

}

These functions (undo,clear) are not properties so how can I use them when I  use RNSketchCanvas in my component? I want to trigger them by clicking buttons. An what do we name them class functions or something else? This is the library https://github.com/terrylinla/react-native-sketch-canvas

```
<RNSketchCanvas
    ref={canvas}
    containerStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent', flex: 1 }}
    canvasStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent', flex: 1 }}           
/>
```